# okular: disable keyboard shortcuts for annotations

Tags: okular

So I want to bind keys `1` and `2` in Okular to display respectively one single page or two facing pages. It seems however that those keys are bound to some annotation tools.

In older versions of Okular I could bind those shortcuts; maybe there were no annotations, I don't know, I don't use annotations. Now it creates a shortcut conflict and I cannot de-assign them from annotations using the “Keyboard shortcuts” menu entry.

(Edit to add: also, when defining the shortcuts `1` and `2` in the relevant dialog box, nothing warns me that these are already assigned, which likely classifies as a bug).

Is there another way to kill the annotations shortcuts so that I can assign keys?

(Okular version 1.11.3. I don't use the remainder of KDE, but I quite like this document viewer).

Answer (score 2):

OK, I solved this; leaving it here in the unlikely case anybody has the same problem.

It turns out that removing *all* the annotation tools (Configuration > Configure Okular > Annotations) also removes the “silent” keyboard shortcuts.

Another possibility would have been to edit `~/.config/okularpartrc`, but that file is a bit unwieldy (the annotations configuration is one huge line of XML) and I am not too confident that any changes made there would have been persistent.